# Python Scrape data file text to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data containing the textarea, I have got the contents of the text.

I tried to convert it into a csv file, but when I opened the converted file. the data that appears is messy and stacked on row 1.

the following is how I use beautifulsoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=46410'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63'
}

datas = []
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
dt = soup.find_all('pre')
for text in dt :
    contents = text.find(id = "data").text
    datas.append([contents])

kepala = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', 'T', 'Height']
writer = csv.writer(open('result/station-56003', 'w', newline=''))
writer.writerow(kepala)
for d in datas: writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: What did you expect `newline=''` to do?

Comment: @OneCricketeer When passing the `newline=“”` argument to the `open()` function, the writer will only write one new line after each row. Without it, there would be a blank line between lines of data in the CSV file. Edit: now I see what your rhetorical question was intended to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is plain text, not a table or CSV, so you'll need to parse it by hand. The format appears to be fixed-width fields delimited by spaces. The below code gives 429 rows and assumes each row is comprised of numbers, spaces and period characters and is 30 characters in width.

As an aside, `writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w'))` leaks memory. Use `with open(...)` to create a context manager that closes the resource automatically when the block ends.

```
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=46410"
request_headers = {
    "user-agent": ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                   "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                   "Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63")
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=request_headers)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
headers = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "T", "Height"]

with open("station-56003", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for line in soup.select_one("#data").text.split("\n"):
        if re.fullmatch(r"[\d. ]{30}", line) and len(line.split()) == len(headers):
            writer.writerow(line.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the input data itself is a csv like. You need to get rid of the headers and split it by `' '`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=46410'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63'
}

datas = []
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
dt = soup.find_all('pre')
for text in dt :
    contents = text.find(id = "data").text
    datas.append(contents)

kepala = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', 'T', 'Height']
writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerow(kepala)
for d in datas: 
    writer.writerows([i.split(' ') for i in d.split('\n')[2:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the data on '\n' and then splitting it again by space.

Note, in the below code I've changed it to find the 'textarea' tag rather than the 'pre' tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=46410'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63'
}

datas = []
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
dt = soup.find_all('textarea')[0].text

datas = dt.split('\n')[2:]

kepala = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', 'T', 'Height']
with open('station-56003', 'w', newline='') as file:
  writer = csv.writer(file)
  writer.writerow(kepala)
  for d in datas: 
    writer.writerow(d.split(' '))
```